# Strange SyntaxError with if statement in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, syntax-error

I keep trying to run a code for a game, but I keep getting a SyntaxError on my if statement, and in the terminal, it keeps pointing at the colon. I am not sure why, and I am just a beginner so I understand if it is weird. Note that the code, has no indentation problems, it is just the copy and pasting.

I've tried using integers and strings, but nothing works. I am not sure what to do.

```
while monster.enemyhealth>0:
    print ("[Your Turn]")
    print ("(1) Smash")
    print ("(2) "+player.secondary_attack)
    print ("(3) "+player.tertiary_attack)
    print ("(4) Backpack")
    print ("(5) Escape Battle")
    battleinput=int(input(">>>")

    if battleinput==1:
        monster.enemyhealth-player.primary_attack.damage=monster.enemyhealth
        print ("You did "+smash.damamge+" to the monster!")
        player.powerpoints-player.primary_attack.powerpointcost=player.powerpoints
        player.health-monster.attackpower=player.health
        print ("The monster did "+str(monster.attackpower)+" to you!")
```

And here's what the error is:

```
File main.py, line 140
if battleinput==1:
                ↑
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expect it to just go over, and the program to run normally.

Comment: Missing close parenthesis on the previous line, as always.

Comment: In the future please make a [mre]

Comment: @jasonharper thank you for the comment but it doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @rossdude123 I just checked and confirmed that is causing the syntax error. However another different error occurs.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you for the help. Can you please specify what this error is because I only get one error.

Comment: @rossdude123 At line 9, `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: @rossdude123 And then after fixing that, at line 10, `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`

Comment: So, this is just a snippet of my program, but the indentation is fine, it's just the copy/pasting that affected it, and I use repl.it, an online IDE editor, so I may not get that, and also, I'm not sure how you got the second error, because that didn't pop at all for me. But I'll try to look into it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @rossdude123 glad I could help at least a bit! Part of posting on SO is making sure your code formatting is correct ;) it doesn't know what to do with tabs for example.

Comment: I fixed the indenting. It looks like [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58811596/2) was part of the problem

Comment: Regarding the second SyntaxError, it's the `monster.enemyhealth-player.primary_attack.damage=monster.enemyhealth` that's invalid. You probably meant `monster.enemyhealth -= player.primary_attack.damage`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work? I'm really confused now.

Comment: Never mind, it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you used fixed spaces for indentation?

```py
while conditions:
    statements
    if conditions:
        statements
```

it seems you have not true indentation where use *if*

Comment: I've checked but it's just the copy pasting that set off the indentation.